# Fast PHP Encryption Algorithm?

Tags: php, performance, encryption

im currently implementing a security module in a voting system and i was wondering what is the fastest way to encrypt (not hash) data in php? I was thinking something something like TEA, but i've never really tested the performance. I would really appreciate if someone share some know-how here.

Comment: What's your usecase? Why are you encrypting the data?

Comment: The *fastest* way is likely XOR. If you provide more details, there might be something more suitable.

Comment: I need to encrypt the data with session key to prevent automated bot voting. But to do that i need fast algo, so there wont be performance hit.

Comment: @Anonymous: You want to prevent bot voting using cookies? Seriously?

Comment: Man, every child knows how to delete them.

Comment: Not cookies, nvm i found an algo to test with.

Comment: @Anonymous: So how are you doing it? It sounds like you're doing it wrong anyway.

Comment: @Anonymous: You need to give more information to give a good answer.  What are your thresholds?  Why is the mcrypt module too slow for you?  The answer might have nothing to do with encryption.  Maybe you're just overwhelming your hardware.  What about splitting the php layer between multiple computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is PHP's **mcrypt** module: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Code sample:

```
// encrypt
$data = 'data to encrypt';
$key = 'mykey';
$vector_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size( MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB );
$encrypted_data = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, substr( sha1( $key ), -9 ), $data, MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB, $vector_size );

// decrypt
$key = 'mykey';
$vector_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size( MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB );
$decrypted_data = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, substr( sha1( $key ), -9 ), $encrypted_data, MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB, $vector_size ), "\0" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,but vector init + 3des is not that fast.

Comment: @Anonymous - In comparison to what?  How fast do you need it?  Did you look up the mcrypt module to see if there's anything in there that would meet your needs?

Comment: actually google still brings me here while [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) has been removed in current PHP 7.2. Anyway [openssl_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)  was always 100-1000 times faster